# What Angular 2 Tour-of-Heroes files do I need to deploy to a web server not running node

Tags: angularjs

I have the Angular 2 Tour-of-Heroes tutorial running on my local machine, but I would like to deploy it to a server not running node. I've tried to upload the node_modules folder, but it is huge and the environment won't doesn't allow .json files. Needless to say, it doesn't work.

I'm sure that I don't need to the .ts files in the app folder since those are generated when tsc command is run. I also think I don't need the systemjs.js, tsconfig.json, and tslint.json files.

**File Structure is:**

```
app
  app.component.js
  app.component.ts
  app.module.js
  app.module.ts
  main.ts
  main.js
  hero.js
  hero.ts
  hero-detail.component.js
  hero-detail.component.ts
  app.component.spec.js.map
  app.component.js.map
  app.component.spec.ts
  app.module.js.map
node_modules
index.html
package.json
styles.css
systemjs.config.extras.js
systemjs.config.js
tsconfig.json
tslint.json
```

**package.json file:**
If I don't want to upload all the node modules files, I have a feeling I have to change this package.json file, but I'm not sure how.

```
{
"name": "angular-quickstart",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
"scripts": {
  "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
  "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
  "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
  "lite": "lite-server",
  "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
  "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
  "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
  "tsc": "tsc",
  "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",

  "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
  "systemjs": "0.19.40",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "rxjs": "5.0.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
  "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
  "typescript": "~2.0.10",

  "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
  "http-server": "^0.9.0",
  "tslint": "^3.15.1",
  "lodash": "^4.16.4",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
  "karma": "^1.3.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
  "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~4.0.14",
  "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

  "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
  "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"
},
"repository": {}
}
```

**Index.html:**
I noticed that I don't have a reference to angular.js file, but the tutorial didn't use it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am not including all the file details as I don't think that they have an impact, but I'm not sure so if you need more details, I will be happy to provide them.

Comment: Don't have the time to write out a full answer atm.. However I can maybe get you started until somebody can give you a good one. Basically the things that you'll need are things that web servers generally will serve to clients. (HTML, CSS, JS). You will also need any files you are dependent on, like the shim's and zone.js. How these are included in your final bundle is through some build step (webpack, system.js) -- or for Angular, you can let angular-cli do it all for you. Sorry if that's not super clear, but hopefully you at least have some words to Google now.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) to create, manage and build the project. Once you build the project using `ng build`, copy the output files from dist folder and paste these files into a server and point the index.html file.